# browser plugin using firebreath

Tags: c++, firefox-addon, npapi, browser-plugin, firebreath

i ve built the sample plugin using firebreath.. Now I m planning to write a plugin that captures all the events from a webpage.

Please help how to do this using firebreath ?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "all the events from a webpage"?  Really need a lot more information to answer this question.  Also, a better forum for this question would probably be the firebreath-dev mailing list or the IRC channel

Comment: All the events in the sense, say all the links in a webpage..

Comment: okay... in a web page, usually events are referring to things like mouse movement, so I would certainly not have expected that to mean links =] glad you clarified.  I see you ask on the firebreath-dev list, so I have responded there.  Sounds like you may not actually want a plugin, but rather an extension. (FireBreath can be used by an extension but cannot be an extension)

Answer (score 2):

You can't capture page events in a plugin; plugins have a specific location on the page, created by an `<object>` or `<embed>` tag, and control the drawing and event handling for that area only. (Flash and QuickTime, for example, are plugins.) What you want to do would be done with JavaScript.

As Taxilian said, it sounds like you have probably conflated NPAPI/ActiveX plugins and browser extensions.

Comment: There is an example in FBTestplugin which captures Mouse events.